# Packaging Sqlite Database with NuGet and C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, nuget

I have a portable library that I want to share across applications. This library uses a somewhat small database for lookup values. It would be idea to ship a NuGet package with a local SQLite DB to read the values from. I've been playing around with changing the *Build Actions* in Visual Studio and am able to get the database to be stored along with the package, but there doesn't seem to be a way to load this resource as a connection. Is doing something like this possible, or should I take an alternate route?